# Test keeps on failing even though function works

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I'm running unit test using with visual studio's native unit test. When I run the function using the same exact code outside the test it works just fine, however, when I run the test it fails.

my test code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../banking/datamanagement.cpp"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <functional>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Tests
{
    TEST_CLASS(Tests)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            datamanagement test("C:\\Users\\wilyx11\\Desktop\\projects\\C++\\Banking_management_system\\banking\\testFile.json");
            int testFileReturn = test.loadfile();
            Assert::AreEqual(1, testFileReturn);
        }
    };
}
```

My function loadfile()

```
int datamanagement::loadfile() {

    jsonFile.open(this->filename);
    if (jsonFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File is loaded" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Failed to open" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }


};
```

I'm new to c++ so any guidance would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Tip: You don't need `this->filename`, you can just do `filename`.

Comment: What does this test print? Does it appear to follow the right branch at least?

Comment: Seeing `#include "../banking/datamanagement.cpp"` is really odd. Is that how your test framework is supposed to be used?

Comment: from the examples, I saw yes @tadman

Comment: Very odd, but alright.

Comment: Is there a clash between the Tests namespace and the TEST_CLASS(Tests)?